# Consistency of Pages List Name between old Pages and new localized Paginas

Tags: 2013, 2010, pages, provisioning, conversion

We're in the process of converting a old SharePoint 2007 system to SharePoint 2013. We found that old sites have a pages list name in the url in English: "Pages", whereas newly created sites have it in Dutch: "Paginas". This seems to be the case as of SharePoint 2010.

We see three approaches:

1. Convert all existing urls' to contain "Paginas";
2. Force SharePoint to keep using "Pages" for new sites;
3. Find out the correct url part for each hyperlink.

**Notes on approach 3**

Unfortunately, our system is clutered with custom code, continually trying to forge site and subsite hyperlinks. We have a hard time trying to figure out in which case "Pages" and in which case "Paginas" is appropriate.

If in the context of an SPWeb, we can find this out using GetPagesListName(web), but we are not always in such a context. We can invoke one, but this seems expensive and error-prone.

Does anyone have thoughts on approaches 1 and 2? Any comments on the fact that for existing sites, the URL's have not been converted from "Pages" to "Paginas" during the upgrade?